# How can i format the output of stat expression in Linux Gnome Terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, fedora, stat

I am really newbie in Linux(Fedora-20) and I am trying to learn basics
I have the following command

```
echo "`stat -c "The file "%n" was modified on ""%y" *Des*`"
```

This command returns me this output

```
The file Desktop was modified on 2014-11-01 18:23:29.410148517 +0000
```

I want to format it as this:

```
The file Desktop was modified on 2014-11-01 at 18:23
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do that with `stat` (unless you have a smart version of `stat` I'm not aware of).

### With `date`

Very likely, your `date` is smart enough and handles the `-r` switch.

```
date -r Desktop +"The file Desktop was modified on %F at %R"
```

Because of your glob, you'll need a loop to handle all files that match `*Des*` (in Bash):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *Des*; do
    date -r "$file" +"The file ${file//%/%%} was modified on %F at %R"
done
```

### With `find`

Very likely your `find` has a rich `-printf` option:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*Des*' -printf 'The file %f was modified on %TY-%Tm-%Td at %TH:%TM\n'
```

### I want to use `stat`

(because your `date` doesn't handle the `-r` switch, you don't want to use `find` or just because you like using as most tools as possible to impress your little sister). Well, in that case, the safest thing to do is:

```
date -d "@$(stat -c '%Y' Desktop)" +"The file Desktop was modified on %F at %R"
```

and with your glob requirement (in Bash):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *Des*; do
    date -d "@$(stat -c '%Y' -- "$file")" +"The file ${file//%/%%} was modified on %F at %R"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 stat -c "The file "%n" was modified on ""%y" *Des* | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}{for(i=1;i<=7;++i)printf("%s ",$i)}{print "at " substr($8,0,6)}'
```

I have use here `awk` modify your code. what i have done in this code, from field 1,7 i printed it using for loop, i need to modify field 8, so i used `substr` to extract 1st 5 character.

Comment: it is working in the case of file having space to, so no need of echo .

Comment: No, it doesn't work with filenames containing spaces. Try it yourself: `touch 'Desk top'` and enjoy.