# How to sort lists with chronological order in Linux Terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, list, shell, terminal

I have this following command in linux terminal(Fedora-20)

```
stat -c "The file "%n" was modified on "%y ** | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}{for(i=1;i<=7;++i)printf("%s ",$i)}{print "at " substr($8,0,5)}' | sort -nr
```

This command gives me the output like this:

```
 The file Question5.sh was modified on 2014-10-29 at 17:30
 The file Question4.sh was modified on 2014-10-29 at 17:30
 The file Question2.sh was modified on 2014-11-01 at 22:51
 The file Question2.sh~ was modified on 2014-11-01 at 22:51
 The file Question1.sh was modified on 2014-10-29 at 18:37
 The file Question1.sh~ was modified on 2014-10-29 at 17:53
```

sort -nr is not working in my case unfortunately..

How can i sort this list in chronological order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work if you want to sort by date and time

```
sort -s -k7 -k9
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a follow-up of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26693387/1815797). Maybe you should have specified what your goal really is. Whatever.

I gave you several possibilities to display the modified date of the files. Here's an adaptation of them to have the files sorted out with respect to modification time:

### With `date` (and Bash)

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
for file in *; do
    date -r "$file" +"%s%tThe file ${file//%/%%} was modified on %F at %R"
done | sort -n | cut -f2-
```

### With `find`

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*' -printf '%T@\tThe file %f was modified on %TY-%Tm-%Td at %TH:%TM\n' | sort -n | cut -f2-
```

### Notes

These are sorted from oldest to newest. If you need the other order, add the `-r` option to `sort`.

These work well with spaces in filenames, but break with newlines in filenames. I don't think you even want to consider such filenames here. To be really safe, you may ignore them altogether like so:

- For the `date` version: add `shopt -s extglob` somewhere at the top, and replace the `for` line with

  ```
  for file in !(*$'\n'*); do
  ```
- For the `find` version: add `\! -name $'*\n*'` in the command as so:

  ```
  find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*' \! -name $'*\n*' -printf '%T@\tThe file %f was modified on %TY-%Tm-%Td at %TH:%TM\n' | sort -n | cut -f2-
  ```
- The `find` version will also show the hidden files. If you don't want them:

  ```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*' \! -name $'*\n*' \! -name '.*' -printf '%T@\tThe file %f was modified on %TY-%Tm-%Td at %TH:%TM\n' | sort -n | cut -f2-
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending `ls -t | xargs` and remove `**` from `stat` as well as the last `sort`

```
ls -t | xargs stat -c "The file "%n" was modified on "%y | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}{for(i=1;i<=7;++i)printf("%s ",$i)}{print "at " substr($8,0,5)}'
```

Then `ls` will sort files chronologically for you, and pass them to `stat` one by one.